Join tables with Entity Framework Core ignores join filter
Recently, I upgraded my project to use Entity Framework Core instead of Entity Framework. I have a query in my project that has recently started timing out.
When I checked the profiler, I noticed that the query is being executed differently than before:
This is the query:
var orders = context.Orders.AsQueryable();
var orderItems = context.OrderItems.AsQueryable();
var customers = context.Customers.AsQueryable();
var statusCodes = statuses.Cast<short>();
var paymentData = context.PaymentData.AsQueryable();

query = 
    from order in orders
    where order.CustomerId == customerId && statusCodes.Contains(order.StatusCode)
    join item in orderItems on order.OrderId equals item.OrderId into itemList
    from customer in customers
    where order.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId &&
          order.Currency == customer.Currency &&
          order.ProductType == customer.ProductType &&
          order.PaymentMethodId == customer.PaymentMethodId
    join payment in context.Payments.AsQueryable() on new
    { OrderId = order.OrderId, ProductType = order.ProductType.Value } equals
    new { OrderId = (int)payment.OrderId, payment.ProductType } into payments
    from paymentResult in payments.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join paymentDetail in paymentData
    on order.OrderId equals paymentDetail.OrderId into paymentDetails
    select new OrderResponse
    {
        OrderId = order.OrderId,
        CustomerId = order.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = order.CustomerName,
        OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
        //...
    };


Relationships:

Orders to OrderItems: one-to-many
Orders to Customers: many-to-one
Orders to Payments: one-to-many (Left Join)
Orders to PaymentData: one-to-many

The profiler shows me this result:
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ...
FROM [Sales].[Orders] AS [order]
LEFT JOIN [Sales].[OrderItems] AS [item] ON [order].[OrderId] = [item].[OrderId]
WHERE ([order].[CustomerId] = @__customerId_0) AND [order].[StatusCode] IN (CAST(1 AS smallint), CAST(2 AS smallint), CAST(3 AS smallint), CAST(4 AS smallint), CAST(5 AS smallint), CAST(6 AS smallint), CAST(7 AS smallint), CAST(8 AS smallint), CAST(9 AS smallint), CAST(81 AS smallint), CAST(82 AS smallint), CAST(89 AS smallint), CAST(90 AS smallint), CAST(91 AS smallint), CAST(99 AS smallint))
ORDER BY [OrderId0]',N'@__customerId_0 varchar(50)',@__customerId_0='62325234'

SELECT [customer].[CustomerId], [customer].[Currency], [customer].[ProductType]
FROM [Sales].[Customers] AS [customer]

SELECT [payment].[OrderId], [payment].[ProductType], [payment].[CollectionDueDate]
FROM [Sales].[Payments] AS [payment]

SELECT [paymentDetail].[OrderId], [paymentDetail].[AccountHolderName], [paymentDetail].[BankAccountNumber], [paymentDetail].[BankName], [paymentDetail].[IachId], [paymentDetail].[Routing]
FROM [Sales].[PaymentData] AS [paymentDetail]

It retrieves the last three tables — all of them without any filters — and since I have a lot of data, running the query has started to take a long time.
Does anyone know how to help me resolve this issue? How can I modify my query to perform a join instead of separate queries for each table?

Why are you writing these joins yourself? Does EF not already know how the tables link together?

Looks like someone called ToList() or ToArray() earlies. You have shown separated queries, but should be only one. EF Core do not have such implicit behavior.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv do you have a suggestion for a solution?

I've seen such behaviour, when top level collection is not IQueryable or IQueryable created from local collection, yes AsQueryable() from local collection. I cannot debug your code, find it by yourself, use logging.

Use navigation properties, don't join.
